# Avoiding ByteBuffer allocation when using NIO Socket

Tags: java, android, memory-management, netty, nio

I'm using Netty 4 on Android (unsupported I know but haven't caused me any trouble so far) to serve a real-time media stream. Every 10-15 seconds or so there is a noticeable lag in the stream which I have essentially tracked down to these:

```
D/dalvikvm(25970): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5283K, 24% free 54631K/71884K, paused 24ms, total 24ms
D/dalvikvm(25970): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 10162K, 24% free 54632K/71792K, paused 24ms, total 25ms
D/dalvikvm(25970): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 13571K, 24% free 54633K/71792K, paused 28ms, total 28ms
D/dalvikvm(25970): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8189K, 24% free 54633K/71792K, paused 25ms, total 26ms
```

The pauses are not catastrophic I suppose, but causes a noticeable annoyance. Looking further in DDMS allocation tracker causes a bit more alarm:

```
1502  15351 byte[]  12  java.nio.ByteBuffer allocate  
  at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:56)   
  at java.nio.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:360)   
  at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doWrite(NioSocketChannel.java:267)    
  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:694)   
  at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.flush0(AbstractNioChannel.java:315)  
  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush(AbstractChannel.java:663)    
  at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadHandler.flush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1038)    
  at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:696)   
  at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.flush(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:677) 
  at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.flush(ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.java:115)   
  at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:696)   
  at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.access$1600(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:30)    
  at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext$WriteAndFlushTask.write(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:1000)  
  at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.run(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:934) 
  at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:370) 
  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:353)
```

This happens basically 30 times a second, each time I write to the Netty `Channel`. Since the top of the allocation stack is in NIO itself, I thought I would give OIO a try but it isn't much better.

In the interest of performance, is there anything I can do so that NIO would reuse buffers rather than making a new one at each write. If not, is there any alternative means of networking in Java which doesn't suffer from this issue?

**EDIT:** I believe the exact bit of NIO code in question is line 431 in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/master/luni/src/main/java/java/nio/SocketChannelImpl.java

Comment: It looks like there's an version of `write()` that takes an external `ByteBuffer`.

Comment: You are right! I now feel rather silly for not having scrolled up a bit further. Perhaps I could check to see if I could get Netty to call that instead...

Comment: This is where Netty calls into the Java libraries: https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/transport/src/main/java/io/netty/channel/socket/nio/NioSocketChannel.java#L266

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a go at changing that tomorrow.

Comment: Well you may be able to configure it given that you're using the `DefaultChannelHandlerContext`.  This implies you can create your own that perhaps uses a different sort of channel factory or something.